# Does reverse biasing hold any meaning in case if both terminals are n type semiconductors?

Tags: transistors, diodes, terminology

When we talk about an n-p-n transistor in common emitter configuration, we often say that emitter-collector circuit (the one towards right) is reverse biased. In what sense it is reverse biased?
Here, both terminals are n-type, for such a thing to be reverse biased must not we put positive voltages across both the n-type terminals?

[image]

Comment: Look at the C-B pn junction and Vcc>Vbb.

Comment: That would mean C-B pn junction is reverse biased. I am confused about C-E.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A BJT has two PN junctions:

1. The Emitter-Base Junction or Emitter junction.
2. The Collector-Base Junction or Collector junction.

So you can say something like *"Emitter junction is forward biased"* or *"collector junction is reverse biased"*. You can not say that the collector-emitter circuit is reverse biased since there is no 'collector-emitter' junction.